# How to implement style sheet on mvc razor file upload control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, razor

I am new in MVC and I have to implement style on mvc razor control actually I want to hide a file upload control and open file upload control on button click I am using razor file upload control

Comment: What does your current markup look like?

Answer (score -1):

Asssuming your upload control is called fileselector, try this...

$('#fileSelector').click();